# How to access parent window method from child window when parent window is closed?

Tags: javascript

I am trying do a things in javascript. window A has a method reload.
window A open window B, B open C and C open D. After opening the D window both B and C will close. Now How can I execute reload method of A window from D window.
window open sequence as follows,
A->B->C->D. 
After opening D, both B and C will close. 
A has reload method. I want to execute reload from D window.

Comment: `I want to execute reload from D window` so do you expect this to reload the window D or the window A ?

Comment: reload window A but the reload function can be called from window D

Comment: So that function will be present only in window A.. and on executing it.. it should have effects only on window A.. correct ?

Comment: Why don't you store a reference to the parent most window, in each window at the time of loading.

Comment: exactly this is @Rajshekar Reddy

Comment: But how Can I do that ? @ Koushik Chatterjee

Comment: They shouldn't be `A -> B -> C-> N`, all of them should be children of `A`...

Comment: @MSHossain check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

store a key `rootWindow` to every window

when you are opening from root window

```
var newWindow = window.open(......);
newWindow.rootWindow = window;
```

and when opening window from any other window

```
var newWindow = window.open(......);
newWindow.rootWindow = window.rootWindow;
```

or else do `window.rootWindow = window` in the root window at the beginning and use

```
var newWindow = window.open(......);
newWindow.rootWindow = window.rootWindow;
```

whenever opening a new window from any window. However this is from the parent side we are setting in child, you can set from the child window side as well.

and at last, from any window, just call `window.rootWindow.reload()`

Comment: window.rootWindow is undefined after closing the parent window

Comment: probably you are doing some mistake, I tested and works fine if I close `B` and `C` window and  window `A` related stuffs from window `D`

Comment: did you test in IE ? it's not working in IE properly

Comment: IE which version? or Edge?

Comment: version 11 IE not edge

Comment: just tested on **IE v11** and working even if you close intermediate windows :)